# Preservation of moments under convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables with first moment uniformly bounded.

If this sequence of random variables converges to $X$ in distribution,

then we have the inequality $ \lim E (|X_n| ) \geq E (|X|). $

I am aware of examples where the inequality is strict; intuitively, the "mass" can escape to infinity as $n$ increases.

But I heard that with the additional assumption $E(|X_n|^{1+\delta}) <C $ for some positive constants $\delta, C$, then we have  $ \lim E (|X_n| ) = E (|X|). $

How can we prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality should read $\mathbb E|X|\leqslant \liminf_{n\to \infty}\mathbb E|X_n|$. The limit in the RHS may not exist (take $X,X_1,X,X_2,\dots,X_n,X,X_{n+1},\dots$ where $(X_j)$ is such that the inequality is strict).

We can show the following:

1. If there is $\delta$ such that $\sup_n\mathbb E|X_n|^{1+\delta}$ is finite, then $\{X_n,n\geqslant 1\}$ is uniformly integrable.
2. If $\{X_n,n\geqslant 1\}$ is uniformly integrable and $X_n\to X$ in distribution, then $\mathbb E(X_n)\to\mathbb EX$.

For the second fact, consider $f_R(x):=|x|\chi_{(-R,R)}(x)$. Fix $\varepsilon\gt 0$ and $R$ such that $\mathbb P\{X\in\{-R,R\}\}=0$ and $\mathbb E[|X|\chi_{|X|\gt R}]+\sup_n\mathbb E[|X_n|\chi_{|X_n|\gt R}]\lt \varepsilon$. Then $\mathbb E[f_R(X_n)]\to \mathbb E[f_R(X)]$. We also have 
$$|\mathbb E|X_n|-\mathbb E|X||\leqslant |\mathbb E[f_R(X_n)]-\mathbb E[f_R(X)]|+2\varepsilon.$$

Comment: This is great. Thank you.